# Two Forms in Class based view of Django

Tags: django

I have two models, each model has it's own form.

In a template page i would like to display two forms.
But i can see that we can define only one model and form.

```
class TicketView(ObjectEditView):  
    form_class = forms.FirstForm
    model = First

    def get(self, request, pk):

        first = get_object_or_404(First, pk = pk)
        return render(request, 'my_folder/file.html', {
            'first': first,
            'form': self.form_class,
        })
```

But how can i pass my second form?

```
form_classes = {forms.FirstForm, forms.SecondForm}
```

some thing like this is possible?

In template for first form i can display a comment field by

```
{% render_field form.comment %}
```

I would like to display second forms fields too like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple forms like this. Of course you need to Import the second form as you did with the first one. In the template you would use `{{form2}}`. The validation for this form also needs to be separate.

```
class TicketView(ObjectEditView):  
    form_class = forms.FirstForm
    form_class2 = forms.SecondForm
    model = First

    def get(self, request, pk):
        first = get_object_or_404(First, pk = pk)
        return render(request, 'my_folder/file.html', {
            'first': first,
            'form': self.form_class,
            "form2":self.form_class2
        })
```

If you have question or this does not work leave a comment :)

Comment: How it's working great. Just need pass to current values to the html now. For eg, for status i am getting drop down, but not getting the current values as selected. We have to do something with model?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do, but to display the form you would not have to. Why are you getting an error?

Comment: it's working great, thanks. Just need pass to current values to the html now. For eg, for status i am getting drop down, but not getting the current values as selected. We have to do something with model?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you need/try to do. In general if you want to use variables from your models you would have to define them in the view like we just defined "form2" and in the template use `{{variableName}}`. I would suggest to ask another question or edit yours so it matches the requirements but since you main issue got solved the proper SO way would be to ask another question.

Comment: just you don't get me wrong I'm not hungry for the points but if you keep adding "Sub Questions" the main question is getting useless for other users @user866933

Comment: @hansTheFranz - I need one clarification. The OP asked about having two forms for two different **models** (_I have two models, each model has it's own form.
_). But in the solution I can seen only **one model**. How do I add the second. **PS** I am not using related models here (and thus will not be using inline formset). Thanks.